# How to connect native C/C++ *.dll to WCF C# hosted in IIS?

Tags: c#, c++, wcf, iis, dll

I need to connect the library native x86 C/C++ *.dll to the service WCF C# 4.0 hosted local in my computer(IIS7.5). I calling service method by http request (method [WebGet]). I get the error:

http://s1.ipicture.ru/uploads/20120509/H8TVURsE.jpg

**DllNotFoundException was unhandled by user code**

**Can not load DLL Li.dll: Access denied (Exclussion from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))**

### **Can you please tell what could be the problem?**

---

The efficiency of the library Li.dll tested in a console application C # - working successfully.

Windows 7 x86
.NET 4.0
VS 2010
IIS7.5

Structure solutions service WCF:

http://s1.ipicture.ru/uploads/20120430/vBXivN71.jpg

### Source Code

native C/C++ x86  Li.dll:

Li.h

```
extern "C" {
    __declspec(dllexport) int __cdecl SimulateGameDLL (int a, int b); 
}
```

Li.cpp

```
#include "Li.h"
extern int __cdecl SimulateGameDLL (int num_games, int rand_in) {
   return 121; 
}
```

C#

WcfServiceLibrary1.IService1

```
[ServiceContract] public interface IService1{
    [OperationContract][WebGet] string GetData();
}
```

WcfServiceLibrary1.Service1

```
public class Service1 : IService1{

public string GetData(){

    ClassLibrary1.Class1 cl = new ClassLibrary1.Class1();
    var rt = cl.M(); 
    return string.Format("Value = : {0}", rt);  
}
}
```

ClassLibrary1.Class1

```
public class Class1{

    [DllImport("Li.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern int SimulateGameDLL(int a, int b);

    public int M() {

        var r = SimulateGameDLL(10, 20);            
        return r;
    }
}
```

**strong text**

Answer (score 1):

Might be you should grant access to user `NETWORK SERVICE` to access the dll file.

Comment: Please tell me where this is configured?

Comment: It's file system permissions. Usually IIS works with NETWORK SERVICE user credentials. My suggestion is grant permission to access the file, you can do this in file properties